# Нужна ли запятая после "в остальном"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> *В остальном*, серьезных изменений не последовало...

Нужна ли запятая после словосочетания "в остальном"?

Comment: А оно точно вводное? Что-то я сомневаюсь, что это не член предложения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В остальном серьезных изменений не последовало. Нет запятой.

В остальном (=в остальных случаях) - это **наречное выражение, к тематике вводных слов не относится и не обособляется, обычно выступает в роли обстоятельства-детерминанта:**

"В остальном это обычный для испанского кинематографа жесткий и натуралистичный в показе агрессии этого мира фильм". "В остальном программа предстоящих праздников не будет отличаться особой новизной и оригинальностью".

Кроме того, "в остальном" может  использоваться **в эллиптических предложения вида "обстоятельство - подлежащее", в этом случае ставится тире:**

"В остальном ― небо и земля". "В остальном ― обыкновенный сапожник". "А в остальном ― неистовый энтузиазм, и море флагов, и восторг, льющийся за грани разумного…"

Answer (score 0):

"В остальном" не вводное, запятая не нужна.

Как авторский знак может употребляться тире (но не в Вашем случае):

[В остальном — есть еще что делать, буду потихоньку исправлять мелочи.](https://www.drive2.ru/l/5374782/)

---

*В остальном - благодарна я доброй судьбе.*

*Я живу, как желаю, - сама по себе.*

*Бог ко мне справедлив и любезен издатель.*

*Старый пес мой взмывает к щеке, как щенок.*

*И широк дивный выбор всевышних щедрот:*

*ямб, хорей, амфибрахий, анапест и дактиль.*

([Зимняя замкнутость](http://ahmadulina.ouc.ru/zimnia-zamknutost.html))